# Screen flashes black when using custom animation controller to dismiss

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have written a custom animation controller to animate my view controller transition. Code as follows :

```
class PopupAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var backgroundColorView: UIView!
    let duration: TimeInterval = 0.35
    var dismiss = false

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        if !dismiss {
            animatePresentTransition(using: transitionContext)
        } else {
            animateDismissTransition(using: transitionContext)
        }
    }

    func animatePresentTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
            let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) else {
                return
        }
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let finalFrameForVC = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVC) // What is this about?
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let snapshotView = fromVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
        snapshotView?.frame = bounds
        backgroundColorView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)
        // Put the window at the bottom of the screen
        toVC.view.frame = finalFrameForVC.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: bounds.size.height)

        // Layer out the views
        containerView.addSubview(snapshotView!)
        containerView.addSubview(backgroundColorView)
        containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

        // The animation happens here
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
            self.backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
            toVC.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
        }, completion: {
            finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })

    }

    func animateDismissTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) else {
            return
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
            self.backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
            let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
            fromVC.view.frame = fromVC.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: bounds.size.height)
        }, completion: {
            finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }

}
```

I have implemented the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` methods in the controller that will use this transition like so :

```
extension PopupViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transitionAnimator.dismiss = false
        return transitionAnimator
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transitionAnimator.dismiss = true
        return transitionAnimator
    }

}
```

When I'm not using a spring in the animation (eg damping set to 1) it works perfectly. However if I include spring in the animation like in this example the screen flashes black when the controller is dismissed:

[image]

Not sure why this is happening. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong where? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same problem here, did you manage to get anywhere with it?

Comment: Anything new on that?